# Can you install an app in a secure silo?

Tags: security

So I am learning Chinese and - because Google is not available in China - Chinese apps tend to be downloaded outside of the play store. To that end, a lot of news apps (especially the good ones which are offered by the state news organisations, e.g. CCTV) have ridiculously wide-ranging security-access levels (i.e. you have to agree that they can read your contacts, your accounts, camera access, the works - even though it has no logical need for such access).
Obviously, not too keen on giving the Chinese government full access to spy on me for the benefit of a news app, but is there a way of setting up a secure silo within Android, in which you can then install apps and dictate what access they can have? 
In some respects, I would like to set up a Great Firewall of Europe on my phone and put the Chinese apps (or at least the ones which seem to come with added surveillance functionality) in there to stop them unnecessarily getting at my contacts etc.
Your help would be greatly appreciated!
Hashamyim

Comment: See my answer to [How can I run apps in an isolated environment on my smartphone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/169048/3573) as a possible solution. Or run those apps as a second user.