# Do virtual space apps in Android provide a fully virtual environment?

Tags: virtualization

There are virtual space apps for Android, such as Parallel Space or Dual Space. I know that we can't access outside files in a virtual environment, but I was able to access them in Dual Space's virtual environment.

Do such virtual space apps provide a fully virtual environment?

Comment: What do you mean with "fully virtual environment"?

Comment: Yes man. You got it right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If virtual space apps are acting like [Parallel Space](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lbe.parallel.intl) then they are virtualizing the app runtime environment. Accessing external storage would not be a problem.

[Commonsware](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) put up a [blogpost](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/17/droidception.html) explaining what is going on under the hood with this virtualization with a caveat:

> However, this sort of virtualization technique – Android apps running inside other Android apps, for an Inception-style experience – requires that you trust the virtualization engine. After all, by definition, it can see all I/O between the app and Android, as it proxies all of that I/O. It is a [[Man-In-The-Middle] MITM attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) on the app.

So if you trust the makers of Parallel Space (or don't care) it is an option to consider.

From my answer: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/169048/3573

Answer (score 3):

ParallelSpace and DualSpace use the same technology if I get their description correctly and this technology has nothing to do with virtualization: they use app cloning

App cloning means that an app is renamed (not the visible name but the app package name such as `com.whatsapp`). Therefore the app is unpacked, modified at certain points to use the new name and then packed and signed with a new signature and afterwards installed.

As Android separates each app a renamed app can be installed side-by-side with the original app. The actual separation is done by the Android OS in exactly the same way it is done for every app.

And just like any other app if the repackaged app stores data in the sd-card section you can access this data.

Comment: Do you have any references for app cloning process?

Comment: @MorrisonChang The general process is not that complicated: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54032434/150978 However I would assume that certain apps require more modifications even on code level.

Comment: Great, the 3rd point answer in your reference is basically my answer. (I knew it was doable but felt brittle as app devs can do various code checks which would result in arms race for detection).

Comment: Thanks man for explaining me the basics behind these apps.

Comment: Parallel Space FAQs page states:  *"07.Does Parallel Space reinstall an app?
Nope, we run and store the app in a virtualization engine."*. So it seems they are running the apps in their own virtual machine, not modifying the app. Haven't investigated myself but this guy has: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41702482/9165920